# Accessing the text of a cell in a UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Is there a way to access a given cell in a table?

For example, if I wanted to access the detail text of only the fourth cell in the table, how do I go about that? Is this mainly done using tags? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:3 inSection:0]];
NSString *detail = cell.detailTextLabel.text
```

Change `indexPathForRow` to the appropriate row number.

Comment: I believe in the abizern's answer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe the answers to this question!

Yes you can get the text of the cell by asking the cell. But really? What if the cell is not visible? What if the user is scrolling and the cell goes off the screen?

You have everything you need in the table view's datasource.

Look at this diagram taken from Apple's [Core Competencies](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/MVC.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008195-CH32-SW1)

[image]

By asking the view for the text from a cell you are breaking MVC. You are supposed to ask the model (the datasource, in this case)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:-

```
   NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:3 inSection:0]; 
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];
```